# Get Checked True/False From GridView in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I've a `GridView` where I've to retrieve the checked values from the `CheckBox` like if in the `GridView` (Row-wise), the row is set to true or false, then I've to get the values like true/false from the `GridView` using `jQuery` and set it to another CheckBox that's out of the `GridView`. So I was trying to use the following:

```
$("#grdDetails tr").click(function () {
       $(this).find('td').each(function (e) {
       $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUserName").val($(this).closest('tr').find("span[id*=lblName]").text());
       $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmail").val($(this).closest('tr').find("span[id*=lblEmail]").text());

         if ($(this).closest('tr').find("input[id*=chkStatus]").attr('checked') == true) //Here I am trying to check the status of the CheckBox from GridView
         {
               $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_chkStatus').attr('checked', true);
         }
         else
         {
               $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_chkStatus').attr('checked', false);
         }
    });
});
```

I am not sure if I am doing the right thing and trying to check status of the `CheckBox` from the `GridView`.

**Note**: I am writing again - The `GridView` has a column **Status** and it shows if any person or member is active with a `CheckBox` in a website. My requirement is when I click on a row, that should retrieve all the information from that specific row and the `CheckBox` status like true/false as well. Right now, I am able to retrieve other values using `jQuery` except the `CheckBox`. As an example, see the below image: In the second row, the `CheckBox` is unchecked that means false. In the form, it should remain unchecked as well.

[image: Check Status]

Comment: You can see the sample here @Asif Ali.

Comment: try `.is(':checked')` instead of `.attr('checked')`

Comment: It worked @Alex Kudryashev - Thanks a lot. You can post it as answer, so I can mark as answer. I've a simple issue on it if you could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `.attr` works fine *when the attribute is hard-coded*. For the properties / states changed on the client side there are other methods. I would rewrite the code like this.

```
 if ($(this).closest('tr').find("input[id*=chkStatus]").is(':checked')/* redundant == true*/)
 {
       $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_chkStatus').prop('checked', true);
 }
 else
 {
       $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_chkStatus').prop('checked', false);
 }
```